# For a new Python project using the latest version of Python should I declare my types as upper or lower case

Tags: python

According to [pep-0585](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/#id6) for the latest versions of Python, it appears we can use `List` and `list` interchangeably for type declarations. So which should I use?

Assume:

1. no requirement for backward compatibility
2. using the latest version of python

```
from typing import List

def hello_world_1(animals: list[str]) -> list[str]:
    return animals

def hello_world_2(animals: List[str]) -> List[str]:
    return animals
```

How can I set up a python linter to enforce consistency and only allow either upper or lowercase `List` for example?

Comment: Using built-in types when possible is just easier to read in my opinion.

Comment: [Pep 20 (The Zen of Python)](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/) says "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."  Seems they're not even giving it lip service any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the current Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#module-contents), `typing.List`  and similar are deprecated.

The docs further state

> The deprecated types will be removed from the typing module in the first Python version released 5 years after the release of Python 3.9.0. See details in [PEP 585](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/)—Type Hinting Generics In Standard Collections.

Concerning enforcing consistency, it says

> It is expected that type checkers will flag the deprecated types when the checked program targets Python 3.9 or newer.

However, I use Pylint personally (not a type checker, admittedly) and I don't believe I've noticed it flagging the deprecated types yet.

Answer (score 3):

PEP585 (linked in the OP) described the imports from `typing` as cumbersome and confusing. This seems to answer the question of which style is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

In general ... it is your choice.  AFAIK, there is no PEP recommendation on which one to use.

If you have decided to use generic type hinting:

- Prior to python 3.9 you *had to* use `typing.List` (for example)
- From python 3.9 onward you can use either `list` or `typing.List`.  Again ... your choice.

---

<sup>(If you are asking for *our* recommendations, that is explicitly off-topic for StackOverflow!  Maybe discuss it with your co-workers, other people working on your projects, ...)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, any comment on the second part of my question regarding enforcing consistency?

Comment: Nope.  No comment.